# Why the downloading speed in Chrome is slow then it is using?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, google-chrome, download, speed

I am using my wifi and it is providing about 2-3 mb/s and Chrome is also using it whole but the while downloading something the speed downloading speed is in kb/s.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network monitor is showing speed in Mbps (megabits per second) and Chrome downloads file in MBps (megabytes per second).

There is a difference between capital B and small b in calculation.
B stands for byte (larger unit, hence capital letter) and b stands for bit. `1 byte = 8 bits` so `(1B)/(8b) = 1`

`2 Mbps = 2 Mbps * 1 = 2 Mb/s * (1B)/(8b) = (2/8) MB/s = 0.25 MBps`

Numerically always divide Mbps with 8, and you will get your true practical speed in MBps.